# why does a space in quotations in a .trim().split("") function in Javascript format the output properly?

Tags: javascript

I was learning about these two function and while experimenting I realised that adding space to the quotations changes the output from an array of individual letter of an array of words/values.

so initially I did this

```
var x = "robin hudson";
var y = x.trim().split("");
console.log(y);
["r","o","b","i","n","h","u","d","s","o","n"]
```

but after adding a space in the .split(""); quotations to be .split(" ");

```
var x = "robin hudson";
var y = x.trim().split(" ");
console.log(y);
["robin","hudson"]
```

Would you please explain to me what difference did this space make?

Comment: [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) explains it pretty clearly

> The split() method returns the new array.
>
> When found, separator is removed from the string and the substrings
>   are returned in an array. If separator is not found or is omitted, the
>   array contains one element consisting of the entire string. If
>   separator is an empty string, str is converted to an array of
>   characters.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `split()` is an optional separator. If the separator is an empty string, the initial string object is converted to an array of characters.

When it's found, the separator is removed from the string and the substrings are returned in an array.

In your second example, when a space is found, the space is removed from the string object, and the substrings are returned in an array.

Answer (score 1):

From moz developer docs

> If separator is an empty string, str is converted to an array of characters

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Tip: If an empty string ("") is used as the separator, the string is split between each character.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp